# Ctrl + U not working to deselect in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 2, when using the Ctrl + D feature to select more of the same, you can use Ctrl + U to go back one. This isn't working in Sublime Text 3. Any ideas?

Comment: Go to View->Show Console, write `sublime.log_commands(True)` there and try to use Ctrl+U. Post here the console output.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you using Emmet? I am having the same problem and there is probably a conflict with the Emmet plugin because the console says:

```
key evt: control+u
command: run_emmet_action {"action": "update_image_size"}
```

**Solution which worked for me:**

1. open the file named `Emmet.sublime-settings`,
2. find `"disabled_keymap_actions": ""`, and
3. replace it with `"disabled_keymap_actions": "update_image_size"`,

Found here: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#overriding-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Totally works. It would be better though not to change default Emmet settings but to add `"disabled_keymap_actions": "update_image_size"` to user settings as @Wernight proposed below

Answer (score 12):

[**Emmet** overrides](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#overriding-keyboard-shortcuts) some keyboard shortcuts. To avoid that, open Sublime Text menu Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Settings – User:

```
{
  "disabled_keymap_actions": "expand_abbreviation, update_image_size"
}
```

The **[FindKeyConflicts](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FindKeyConflicts)** package allows to simply find other similar conflicts.